# What causes coloured lines down my screen after it self shutdown?

Tags: boot, display

I was in the middle of screen recording when my computer restarted itself.

When it booted up, I saw this screen:

[image]

Is it likely to be graphics card, hard drive or screen?

Comment: Is the monitor connection DVI, display port, or VGA?  Are you using any video cable adapters?

Answer (score 7):

Definitely not the hard drive.  It could be the screen or the graphics card, but it's more likely the graphics card given that the computer spontaneously rebooted.

Easiest way to tell would be to hook up a different screen and see if you get the same results.  If you do, then it's the video card.  Your only option is to replace it.

Comment: +1 The card probably overheated causing a shutdown during the intense capture operation and when it rebooted, it's still hot and having a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be either the screen itself or the connection to the computer.

Do the artifacts appear over the built-in monitor menu?  If so, it's the screen.

Does reseating either end of the video cable help?